# Generate authorization digest header with urllib2 or requests

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests, digest-authentication

I am trying to generate the digest authorization header for use in a python test case. Because of the way the code base works, it is important that I am able to get the header as a string. 
This header looks something like this

```
Authorization: Digest username="the_user", realm="my_realm", nonce="1389832695:d3c620a9e645420228c5c7da7d228f8c", uri="/some/uri", response="b9770bd8f1cf594dade72fe9abbb2f31"
```

I think my best bets are to use either urllib2 or the requests library.

**With urllib2, I have gotten this far:**

```
au=urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler()
au.add_password("my_realm", "http://example.com/", "the_user", "the_password")
```

but I can't get the header out of that.

**With requests, I have gotten this far:**

```
requests.HTTPDigestAuth("the_user", "the_password")
```

But I when I try to use that, in a request, I am getting errors about setting the realm which I can't figure out how to do

Answer (score 4):

If you're prepared to contort yourself around it, you can get the `requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth` class to give you the right answer by doing something like this:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

chal = {'realm': 'my_realm', 'nonce': '1389832695:d3c620a9e645420228c5c7da7d228f8c'}
a = HTTPDigestAuth('the_user', password)
a.chal = chal

print a.build_digest_header('GET', '/some/uri')
```

If I use `'the_password'` as the user's password, that gives me this result:

```
Digest username="the_user", realm="my_realm", nonce="1389832695:d3c620a9e645420228c5c7da7d228f8c", uri="/some/uri", response="0b34daf411f3d9739538c7e7ee845e92"
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble generating the nonce. I found this: `md5("%d:%s" % (time.time(), 'the_realm')).hexdigest()}` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You've got an unmatched brace at the end.

Comment: It also looks like you should only MD5 the realm, not the whole string. So the appropriate string would be: `"%d:%d" % (time.time(), md5('the_realm').hexdigest())

Answer (score 0):

When I tried @Lukasa answer I got an error:

> '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'chal'

So I solved it in a slightly dirty way but it works:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

chal = {'realm': 'my_realm',
        'nonce': '1389832695:d3c620a9e645420228c5c7da7d228f8c'}
a = HTTPDigestAuth("username", "password")
a.init_per_thread_state()
a._thread_local.chal = chal

print(a.build_digest_header('GET', '/some/uri'))
```